# how to prove the range of a  closed linear operator is closed ?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

The closed range theorem tells us that given two banach spaces X,Y,and a closed densely defined linear operator T：$X \to Y$. We have the following equivalence $R(T)$ is closed in $Y \iff R(T^{*})$ is closed in $X^{*} \iff R(T)=N(T^{*})^{\perp}$.  This gives a complete characterisation, but I don't know whether it's convenient  or not for application.

**Question 1:** Can anyone pose some examples to use this theorem ?

When we consider the case that $T$ is a bounded operator, it's true that if the range $TX$ has finite codimension in $Y$, then $TX$ is closed. So it seems that there are lots of bounded operators whose range is not closed. For instance, when $X=L^{p},1 \leq p<2$, $Y=L^{p'}$, where p' is the dual index. $T$ represents the fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$. Then

**Question 2:** Is $\mathcal{F}L^{p}$  closed in $L^{p'}$? I believe the range is not closed. BTW, I only know that the map is not surjective, if it is not closed, then we can see that actually the range is much smaller than $L^{p'}$

Comment: Your grammar, punctuation, and TeXing were poor.  You should take pains to make your question readable before posting.

Comment: Arg, Bill - I had it all fixed up a moment ago :)

Comment: Sorry our edits overlapped. I think it is OK now. I'm done.

Comment: That's ok. It's your area of expertise, I shall leave it in your more experienced hands.

Comment: Sorry for that,I'm trying to do a better job.

Comment: Also note that the title (how to prove) is not very consistent with the questions in text, actually a common flaw here. (The effect is usually that you mainly get an answer to the question in the title). 

Answer (score 6):

$\mathcal{F}L^{p}$ is not closed in $L^{p'}$ unless $p=2$. $\mathcal{F}$ is one to one and for $1<p $ the space $\ell_p$ embeds isomorphically into $L^p$ but not into  $L^{p'}$.  Alternatively, $\mathcal{F}$ has dense range but $L^p$ is not isomorphic to $L^{p'}$. For $p=1$ use the fact that the closure of $\mathcal{F}L^{1}$ is a $C(K)$ space and thus contains a subspace isomorphic to $c_0$ while  $c_0$ does not embed into $L^1$. Or see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8085/range-of-the-fourier-transform-on-l1) MO question.

Comment: thanks,and I also learned the nontrivial fact that $L^p$ is not isomorphic to $L^{p'}$ if $p \ne p'$ from 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79713/lp-mathbbr-vs-lq-mathbbr 
 