# Characterizations of Wiener algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, fourier-transform

The Wiener algebra $\mathcal W$ is defined as $\text{Fourier}(L^1(\mathbb R))$, i.e. the image by the Fourier transform of $L^1(\mathbb R)$. Riemann-Lebesgue's lemma ensures that
$$
\mathcal W\subset C^0_{(0)}(\mathbb R)=\{\phi\text{ continuous on }\mathbb R, \lim_{\vert \xi\vert\rightarrow+\infty}\phi(\xi)=0\} .
$$

1. I believe that the injection $\mathcal W\subset C^0_{(0)}(\mathbb R)$ is not onto. Is it due to Hardy? Gaier? Both at different times?
2. Is there an "explicit" function $\phi\in C^0_{(0)}(\mathbb R)$ whose inverse Fourier transform (say in the distribution sense) does not belong to $L^1(\mathbb R)$?
3. Is there a functional analytic reason for why the Banach spaces $L^1(\mathbb R)$ and $C^0_{(0)}(\mathbb R)$ cannot be isomorphic?

Answer (score 4):

For (2), the answers to [Does there exist a continuous function of compact support with Fourier transform outside L^1?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3764/does-there-exist-a-continuous-function-of-compact-support-with-fourier-transform/) may be helpful.

For (3), the answer is yes, although one always needs to rely on some theoretical background. My preferred argument is to note that every bounded linear map $C_0({\bf R}) \to L^1(X,\mu)$ ($X$ and $\mu$ arbitrary) is weakly compact, hence if the two spaces were isomorphic then the identity map on $C_0({\bf R})$ would be weakly compact, hence $C_0({\bf R})$ would be a reflexive Banach space, which it isn't.

I don't know to what extent these remarks answer (1) -- are you looking for an actual reference as to who showed the FT is not surjective?

Comment: As for (3), $C^0_{(0)}$ contains a copy of $c_0$ (take the linear span of a sequence disjointly supported functions), whereas for $L_1(\mu)$ this is clearly impossible for many reasons (*e.g.* because $L_1(\mu)$ is weakly sequentially complete).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Question (1) was only intended to clarify the priorities in a reference list.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that all functions in Wiener algebra is uniformly continuous. So This gives examples to (2).

In addition, https://mathoverflow.net/a/203514/514950 gives a link to a function which is uniformly continuous but not in $\mathcal W$.

Comment: Regarding your first line: every function in $C^0_{(0)}({\mathbb R})$ is uniformly continuous, so your observation doesn't seem to address point (2). Regarding your second line: you seem to just be repeating what I wrote 8 years ago...