# Function with non Riemann-integrable Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-transform

Does there exist a compactly supported continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb R$, such that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^n\widehat{f}(x)\ dx
$$
does not exist?

Here $\widehat f$ is the Fourier transform of $f$.

Comment: I think it exists. You should probabaly modify the classical example of P. Du Bois Reymond of  of a continuous periodic function which has Fourier series which diverges at some point.

Comment: What about the answer by @jjcale to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/3764/does-there-exist-a-continuous-function-of-compact-support-with-fourier-transform? The function is $\frac{1/2-x}{\log(1/x)} 1_{[0,1/2]}$.

Comment: @Dispersion: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^n\widehat{f}$
 could still exist though, even when $\widehat{f}\notin L^1$.

Comment: Ah yes you are right, I overlooked that we were taking the symmetric limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. We can adapt the functional analytic argument for the existence of continuous functions with divergent Fourier series.

Fix a $\varphi\in C[-2,2]$ with $0\le\varphi\le 1$, $\varphi(\pm 2)=0$, and $\varphi=1$ on $[-1,1]$, and consider the functionals $L_n: C[-2,2]\to\mathbb C$
$$
L_n(g) = \int_{-n}^n \widehat{\varphi g}\, dt = (D_n *(\varphi g))(0) =\int_{-2}^2 D_n(t)\varphi(t)g(t)\, dt .
$$
Here $D_n(t)=\frac{\sin nt}{t}$ is the Dirichlet kernel.

For the (discontinuous) function $g(t)=\operatorname{sgn}(D_n(t))$ we have $\|g\|_{\infty}=1$,
$$
|L_n(g)|\ge \int_{-1}^1 |D_n(t)|\, dt\gtrsim \log n .
$$
Since we can get close to this situation also with continuous functions $g$, it follows that $\|L_n\|\to\infty$, and thus the uniform boundedness principle shows that there must be $f=\varphi g$ for which $\int_{-n}^n \widehat{f} = L_n(g)$ diverges (in fact, is unbounded).

Comment: Nice use of the uniform boundedness principle. Do you think an explicit example can be constructed here?

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Not sure, but it's certainly possible. Maybe one can just take one of the constructions of a continuous (and periodic) function with divergent Fourier series, and $f-c$ might still work in the current setting.